# Is there a way to block CURL to fetch data on my site?

Tags: php, curl

I currentyly use this code to block wget and libwww

```
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Wget" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^libwww-perl" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

is there one for curl?

Comment: That only blocks them until the user sighs and overrides the user-agent string. Neither Wget not LWP (and yes, it is LWP not libwww) are "bad", both tools are well behaved that respect robots.txt when in mirroring mode.

Comment: @Quentin how can i block them then?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, I am sure `curl` has a default User-Agent, but that is obviously something that can be changed as easily as `-H 'User-Agent=Poop'`

In fact, I think there is a switch specifically for setting the user agent.  `-A`

Answer (score 3):

curl user agents can be changed at any time. The reason curl exists is that you can change pretty much everything on your query.

You can block them, but once they change the use agent, they will have access again.

I recommend you block the IP address instead or the whole subnet just to be sure.

Example:

```
deny from aa.bb.cc.dd  ff.gg.hh.0/24
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check preferred language, http version, remote domain and such things.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you stop it for a while, an attacker will come here on this blessed site and get a dozen answers how to break your defence.

So, I hate it but there is no way to block.
You can ban some IP's eventually, you can place some honeypost to spot bots but everything is breakable.
So, you'd better don't care about the data but care of the service.
As long as your service being the best, your site will be the first. And no scraping will help them good-for-nothings who wants to feed on other people's labour.

Answer (score 0):

Add a captcha if there are two many requests from a single ip address?

Comment: Oh come on, take example from Google. And comment when you vote down to describe the reason for it.

Comment: +1 i like the captcha idea - but my question is about curl how can you put a captcha on a CURL request?

Comment: @eric, I guess this is a probably a better solution, since it will stop any client (including curl) from abusing your website (or scraping content from your website). You can't just base it on User-Agent unfortunately since it is rather easy to change the User-Agent. Google uses the same technique with the CAPTCHA if you attempt to get too many search results out of it. So even with curl, when the captcha  is activated for this IP, curl will only download the html containing the captcha image